# Open MPI + Scalasca :Can not run mpirun command with option --prefix

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

I have installed [scalasca(scorep,cube,..)](http://www.scalasca.org/software/scalasca-2.x/download.html)with Open MPI for peformance measurement . When i add an option :
" --prefix = /my-path" to mpirun, "scalasca - analyze" can not be executed ( Aborted ) .
My command :
`scalasca -analyze mpirun -np 1 --host localhost --prefix /home/as/lib/bin /home/as/Documents/a.out` 
"/home/as/lib" is the installed Open MPI directory.
And error :
`S=C=A=N: Abort: Target executable`/home/as/lib/bin' is a directory!` 
If without "--prefix" , it runs normally .But i need "-- prefix" option to run it on a cluster.
I have installed Open MPI on all of cluster machines with same path (/home/as/lib) .
So how to fix it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open MPI adds an implicit `--prefix` option if `orterun` (or any of its symlinks like `mpirun`, `mpiexec`, etc.) is called with full path. In other words:

```
$ /home/as/lib/bin/mpirun ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
$ mpirun --prefix /home/as/lib ...
```

If your really really need to pass that `--prefix` option, e.g. because Open MPI is installed on the cluster nodes in a different directory than on the front-end node, then quote the entire parameter:

```
$ scalasca -a mpirun -np 1 --host localhost "--prefix /home/as/lib" /path/to/execuable
```

The same applies to any other parameter to `mpirun`. You could even quote them all, just to be on the safe side:

```
$ scalasca -a mpirun "-np 1" "--host localhost" "--prefix /home/as/lib" /path/to/execuable
```

**Hint:** When building your own version of Open MPI, do it with `--enable-orterun-prefix-by-default`. That way `--prefix` will be added automatically even when `orterun`/`mpirun`/`mpiexec` is not called with the full path to it. Also, `--enable-wrapper-rpath` is a good choice of build option, which will prevent clashes with other versions of the library.